# I have problem with adding Admob to my project

Tags: java, android-studio, dependencies, admob

**When I adding this to my build.gradle (Module):**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
```

**This line of code is underlined in red:**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

**Error description:**
- All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.1, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0

I was trying to implement and change customtabs from version 26.1.1 to 27.1.1 in dependiences but it still not working:((

I want get any help in this

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue - i update api and its fine now.
please follow this instructions:

open SDK Manager:
[image]

Install the latest one:
[image]

restart your IDE (android studio) open gradle and change to:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```